# Angularjs soap library throws a typeError on Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, soap

I'm using the soap service for AngularJS from [Andrew McGivery](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap)

It works perfectly when called from Chrome but it returns a typeError on Firefox and IE11.

> TypeError: e is null at angular.soap.js line 16

The code in question is as follows:

```
.factory("$soap",['$q',function($q){
    return {
        post: function(url, action, params){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            //Create SOAPClientParameters
            var soapParams = new SOAPClientParameters();
            for(var param in params){
                soapParams.add(param, params[param]);
            }

            var soapCallback = function(e){
                //ERROR THROWN ON LINE BELOW
                if(e.constructor.toString().indexOf("function Error()") != -1){
                    deferred.reject("An error has occurred.");
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(e);
                }
            }

            SOAPClient.invoke(url, action, soapParams, true, soapCallback);

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        setCredentials: function(username, password){
            SOAPClient.username = username;
            SOAPClient.password = password;
        }
    }
}]);
```

*e* in Chrome is the object returned by my webservice (user object), in Firefox it's null and I don't know where to look in the library to debug the problem.

**UPDATE:**

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('SoapCtrl', function($soap) {

    this.login = function(credentials) {

        $soap.post('MYAPI', 'MYMETHOD', {login: credentials.login, password: credentials.password}).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.userid);
        });
    }

})
```

I also tried calling the same webservice from the jquery plugin [jquery.soap](https://plugins.jquery.com/soap/) inside my angular application and I get the expected behaviour in both Chrome and Firefox.

**LAST UPDATE**

Since this is a professional project, we decided to move on to a plugin that works. [jquery.soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap)

2 issues have been posted on the [author's page](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap/issues) with no answer for the moment.

I would have awarded the bounty to a valid answer but half the bounty is going automatically to the answer with 2 upvotes...

Comment: Is your API on the same domain as webpage? Do you see your API requests in FireBug as successful? This error is thrown when API request failed. I have made a simple test page and angular-soap works just fine for me (http://ypnh.shkryob.webfactional.com/soap/).

Comment: @KostyaShkryob the API is not on the same domain but we've configured CORS and the service works on Chrome. In firebug I can see the expected response from the webservice. It just throws the exception above and doesn't continue. I have the same setup as you have in that link and I call $soap in the same way.

Comment: Browsers may work with CORS headers slightly differently. May be you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true or some other

Comment: I can see Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to true in firebug

Comment: @gyc What about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, check if it is there or not also check by removing credentials and let me know the result then ?

Comment: Allow-Origin header is there as well. The bug comes from the lib itself because the service works with other libs (jquery.soap and pure js) in FF, IE, Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the function `SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName`
I change the line
`return document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);`
For
`return document.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", tagName);`

work for me!

Answer (score 2):

On the library, check the file soapclient.js, on the line 195

```
SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest = function(method, async, callback, wsdl, req) 
{
    var o = null;
    var nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, method + "Result");
    if(nd.length == 0)
        nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, "return");   // PHP web Service?
    if(nd.length == 0)
    {
        if(req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultcode").length > 0)
        {
            if(async || callback)
                o = new Error(500, req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            else
                throw new Error(500, req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);           
        }
    }
    else
        o = SOAPClient._soapresult2object(nd[0], wsdl);
    if(callback)
        callback(o, req.responseXML);
    if(!async)
        return o;
}
```

if you say that in firefox the `e` value it's `null` it's because in this method the `o` variable never it's set. Debug this method will be a help.

Comment: I've already debugged that method. I haven't found anything except that the variable is set in Chrome and not in Firefox.

Comment: I read your update and see that you will use jquery soap. You will move your project to jquery or you'll integrates this library with angular. If you use angular, i'd recommend do this using angular directives.

Comment: I installed jquery.soap with bower in my angular app. For the moment the method is called directly in a controller but will make it a service in the future.